# AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'author'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, nextcord

my nextcord bot was supposed to get the author id but instead gives out an error

```
line 372, in creds
member_data = load_member_data(message.author.id)
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'author
```

Here's the code

```
@bot.slash_command(name='credits', description='Checks social credit score', guild_ids=guild_id)
async def creds(message):
    member_data = load_member_data(message.author.id)
    await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} has "+ str(member_data.wallet) +" Social Credit Points")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use message.user, also that would be returning an interaction, so it would be more standardized to use "interaction" instead of "message" as the var name, just to make your question more clear for the future.

```py
member_data = load_member_data(message.user.id)
await message.channel.send(f"{message.user.mention}...
```